# Android : Fragment Overlay Actionbar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, fragment, overlay, transparent

Now my image in layout still below action bar. how to display image with overlay action bar in Fragment ? so my image can be transparent with action bar

this is my layout file:

```
`<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
<android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/img_detail_now_playing"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="top"
android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
</android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
android:clickable="true"
android:src="@android:drawable/ic_media_play"
app:fabSize="normal"
app:layout_anchor="@id/img_detail_now_playing"
app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
app:rippleColor="#FFF" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>`
```

any advice about my layout ?

[Current Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ycDp9.png)

Comment: code please couldnt help you

Comment: @siddhesh : sory forget to post my code before